# Changing geom_point shape for specific values in a line

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a line graph with several lines, in which I want to highlight certain values with a different geom_point shape.

The dput of a similar data to mine is:

```
structure(list(Iso = structure(1:9, .Label = c("a", "b", "c", 
"d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"), class = "factor"), z1 = c(342.6, 
8.94, 6.91, 3.96, 1.89, 4.38, 1.43, 5.18, 189.1), z2 = c(187.34, 
2.8, 8.42, 8.24, 2.36, 2.34, 7.6, 0.5, 136.01)), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(Iso = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), z1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), z2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

This is the code:

```
library(readr)
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)

y <- read_csv("dummy.csv")

y$Iso <- factor(y$Iso, levels=y$Iso)

##
plot <- ggplot(y,aes(Iso,group=1)) +theme_bw() + ggtitle('') +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + 
  geom_point(aes(y=z1, colour='z1'), na.rm=FALSE, size=3, shape=16) + 
  geom_point(aes(y=z2, colour='z2'), na.rm=FALSE, size=3,shape=16) +
  geom_line(aes(y=z1, colour='z1'), na.rm=FALSE, linetype=1,size=1) +
  geom_line(aes(y=z2, colour='z2'), na.rm=FALSE,linetype=3, size=2) +
  xlab('') +ylab('ZZ/CI') + scale_y_log10(limits=c(0.1,2000), breaks=c(1e-1,1,1e1,1e2,1e3))
##
plot + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5,size=19, face='bold'), 
             axis.text.y = element_text(size=12), 
             axis.title.y = element_text(size=15)) + 
  scale_colour_manual(name='',breaks=c('z1','z2'),values= c('brown','wheat'),labels= c('z1','z2')) + 
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list (size = c(.75,.75),linetype=c(1,3),shape=c(16,16))))
```

I use the guide for every cosmetic element in order to make the legend more legible.

The data

```
# A tibble: 9 x 3
  Iso       z1     z2
  <fct>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 a     343.6   187.34  
2 b       8.94   2.8 
3 c       6.91   8.42
4 d       3.96   8.24
5 e       1.89   2.36
6 f       4.38   2.34
7 g       1.43   7.6 
8 h       5.18   0.5 
9 i     189.1   136.01
```

For example, in the case of these data, I want to change the shape from 16 to 13, in z1 for '342.6','1.43', and '5.18', and in z2 for '187.34,'2.36','7.6' and '0.5'.
How can I proceed?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Have another categorical column eg `shape = z1 > 100`. Then put `shape` in `aes`

Comment: How can I do that since the numbers I want to highlight are from very different ranges and those I do not want to highlight are within the same ranges?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should consider reformatting your data to long format, as it saves a lot of duplication. Secondly, you need to specify a new column in your data, which you map to shape. If there is no pattern like *any value larger than 100* you need to cherry-pick the values you want to highlight by hand.

The following code should do what you want:

```
library(tidyverse)
y <- structure(list(Iso = structure(1:9, .Label = c("a", "b", "c", 
                                                    "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"), 
                                    class = "factor"), 
                    z1 = c(342.6,  8.94, 6.91, 3.96, 1.89, 4.38, 1.43, 5.18, 189.1), 
                    z2 = c(187.34, 2.8, 8.42, 8.24, 2.36, 2.34, 7.6, 0.5, 136.01)), 
                    row.names = c(NA, -9L),
                    class = c("data.frame")) 

## transform to long format
y.long <- y %>% gather(type, value, -Iso)

## add a new column which 'marks' the special rows
## NOTE: since we moved to long format rows corresponding to z2 are starting now at row 10
y.long <- y.long %>% mutate(highlight = ifelse(type == "z1",
                               ifelse(row_number() %in% c(1, 7, 8), 
                                      "special", "normal"),
                               ifelse(row_number() %in% c(10, 14, 16, 17), 
                                      "special", "normal")))

## in your ggplot you can now map the columns to the graphical elements like so:
ggplot(y.long, aes(Iso, value, 
                   color = type, linetype = type, shape = highlight,
                   group = type)) +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  geom_line(aes(size = type)) +
  scale_y_log10(limits = c(0.1, 2000), breaks = c(1e-1, 1, 1e1, 1e2, 1e3)) +
  scale_color_manual("", values = c(z1 = "brown", z2 = "wheat")) +
  scale_size_manual("", values = c(z1 = 1, z2 = 2), guide = "none") +
  scale_shape_manual("", values = c(normal = 16, special = 13), guide = "none") +
  scale_linetype_manual("", values = c(z1 = "solid", z2 = "dotted"), guide = "none") +
  labs(x = "", y = "ZZ/CI") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x  = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, size = 19, face = "bold"), 
        axis.text.y  = element_text(size = 12), 
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 15))
```

This results in the following plot:

[image: Linechart]

You can adapt the `mutate` satement to include/exclude other rows and the `scale_*` functions to show/hide legends.

---

Theoretically, you could use something like this in your  `mutate`

```
mutate(highlight = ifelse(value %in% c(343.6, 1.43, 5.18, 187.34, 
                                       2.36, 7.6, 0.5), 
                          "special", "normal"))
```

but due to floating point issues (cf. for instance [this article](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Numbers/Comparing_floating_point_numbers/)), i would **not** do this and rather select by row number (as I did) or any other suitable criterion, or use `all.equal` to make proper floating point comparisons.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time to help me. The code works well with the exception of 1 point. I have more than 2 'ifelse' I have 5 z columns. The first 2 go through, but it ignores the last 3. How should I proceed? Also, I saw that the highlight attributes a type of shape to all 'normal' labelled values. I have a series, let's say 'z3'. How do I make it without a shape?

Comment: Since I couldn't make the if else work, I used the selection by numbers, the one you wouldn't do.